# XSL Sort for XML

Tags: java, xml, xslt

Please find the input and output xml files. The XML is sorted on "Code" node ( sorted on CodeValue).

INPUT XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Service>
    <Account>
        <AccountNumber>AB1234</AccountNumber>       
        <Code>
            <CodeType>ABC</CodeType>
            <CodeValue>3456</CodeValue>
        </Code>
        <Code>
            <CodeType>ZCR</CodeType>
            <CodeValue>1234</CodeValue>
        </Code>
        <Bonus>
            <BonusDescription>INCR</BonusDescription>
            <BonusOfferNumber>1004</BonusOfferNumber>
        </Bonus>
        <Bonus>
            <BonusDescription>BNP</BonusDescription>
            <BonusOfferNumber>1326</BonusOfferNumber>
        </Bonus>
        <AccountOption>
            <AccountOptionNumber>1</AccountOptionNumber>
            <Supplier>
                <SupplierName>HSBC</SupplierName>
                <SupplierDetails>UK</SupplierDetails>
            </Supplier>
            <Supplier>
                <SupplierName>BARCLAYS</SupplierName>
                <SupplierDetails>US</SupplierDetails>
            </Supplier>
        </AccountOption>
    </Account>    
    <Account>
        <AccountNumber>AC7658</AccountNumber>       
        <Code>
            <CodeType>HGV</CodeType>
            <CodeValue>6780</CodeValue>
        </Code>
        <Code>
            <CodeType>MNR</CodeType>
            <CodeValue>67</CodeValue>
        </Code>
        <Bonus>
            <BonusDescription>BNP</BonusDescription>
            <BonusOfferNumber>5678</BonusOfferNumber>
        </Bonus>
        <Bonus>
            <BonusDescription>INCR</BonusDescription>
            <BonusOfferNumber>7804</BonusOfferNumber>
        </Bonus>
        <AccountOption>
            <AccountOptionNumber>9</AccountOptionNumber>
            <Supplier>
                <SupplierName>NAT</SupplierName>
                <SupplierDetails>US</SupplierDetails>
            </Supplier>
            <Supplier>
                <SupplierName>LKM</SupplierName>
                <SupplierDetails>GB</SupplierDetails>
            </Supplier>
        </AccountOption>
    </Account>    
</Service>
```

OUTPUT XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Service>
    <Account>
        <AccountNumber>AB1234</AccountNumber>       
        <Code>
            <CodeType>ZCR</CodeType>
            <CodeValue>1234</CodeValue>
        </Code>
        <Code>
            <CodeType>ABC</CodeType>
            <CodeValue>3456</CodeValue>
        </Code>
        <Bonus>
            <BonusDescription>INCR</BonusDescription>
            <BonusOfferNumber>1004</BonusOfferNumber>
        </Bonus>
        <Bonus>
            <BonusDescription>BNP</BonusDescription>
            <BonusOfferNumber>1326</BonusOfferNumber>
        </Bonus>
        <AccountOption>
            <AccountOptionNumber>1</AccountOptionNumber>
            <Supplier>
                <SupplierName>HSBC</SupplierName>
                <SupplierDetails>UK</SupplierDetails>
            </Supplier>
            <Supplier>
                <SupplierName>BARCLAYS</SupplierName>
                <SupplierDetails>US</SupplierDetails>
            </Supplier>
        </AccountOption>
    </Account>    
    <Account>
        <AccountNumber>AC7658</AccountNumber>       
        <Code>
            <CodeType>MNR</CodeType>
            <CodeValue>67</CodeValue>
        </Code>
        <Code>
            <CodeType>HGV</CodeType>
            <CodeValue>6780</CodeValue>
        </Code>
        <Bonus>
            <BonusDescription>BNP</BonusDescription>
            <BonusOfferNumber>5678</BonusOfferNumber>
        </Bonus>
        <Bonus>
            <BonusDescription>INCR</BonusDescription>
            <BonusOfferNumber>7804</BonusOfferNumber>
        </Bonus>
        <AccountOption>
            <AccountOptionNumber>9</AccountOptionNumber>
            <Supplier>
                <SupplierName>NAT</SupplierName>
                <SupplierDetails>US</SupplierDetails>
            </Supplier>
            <Supplier>
                <SupplierName>LKM</SupplierName>
                <SupplierDetails>GB</SupplierDetails>
            </Supplier>
        </AccountOption>
    </Account>    
</Service>
```

Comment: You can use `xsl:sort`; see an example [here](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_sort.asp)

Answer (score 1):

I could describe `<xsl:sort>` in detail, but w3schools can do so better than I:

http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/el_sort.asp

You can define a template to sort any node by it's value with a slight modification to the identity template:

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()">
          <xsl:sort />
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Based on your comments, I believe you need something like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:param name="sort" />

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="name() = $sort">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()">
            <xsl:sort />
          </xsl:apply-templates>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: w3schools != the W3C. The two are in no way affiliated. They are not a standards body and should not be quoted as such.

Comment: Good point. I meant to say w3schools.. not the first time I've made that mistake.

Answer (score 0):

As you haven't stated how the data should be sorted it is hard to give an exact answer.

The `xsl:sort` element can be used to sort listings, as with the for-each selects in the inelegant example below.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:for-each select="//Account">
      <xsl:for-each select="Code">
        <xsl:sort select="CodeValue" data-type="number"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="."></xsl:copy-of>    
      </xsl:for-each>
      <xsl:for-each select="Bonus">
        <xsl:sort select="BonusOfferNumber" data-type="number"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="."></xsl:copy-of>    
      </xsl:for-each>
      <xsl:for-each select="AccountOption">
        <xsl:sort select="AccountOptionNumber" data-type="number"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="AccountOptionNumber"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="Supplier">
            <xsl:sort select="SupplierName"/>
            <xsl:copy-of select="."></xsl:copy-of>    
        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that `Code` is sorted numerically by `CodeValue`, `Bonus` numerically by `BonusOfferNumber` and `Supplier` alphabetically by `SupplierName`.

Comment: Due to space constraint,proving the format as below.<Ser><Acc><AccNum>AB12</AccNum><Cde><CdType>ABC3</CodeType><CodeVal>12</CodeVal></Cde><Cde><CdType>ZCR5</CdeType><CdVal>32</CdVal></Code><Bonus><BonusDes>INCR</BonusDes><BonusOffNum>1004</BonusOffNum></Bonus><Bonus><BonusDes>BNP</BonusDes><BonusOffNum>1326</BonusOffNum></Bonus><AccOpt><AccountOptNumber>1</AccountOpNumber><Supplier><SupplierName>HSBC</SupplierName><SupplierDetails>UK</SupplierDetails></Supplier><Supplier><SupplierName>BARCLAYS</SupplierName><SupplierDetails>US</SupplierDetails></Supplier></AccountOption></Acc>

Comment: The requirement is , i would pass on the node to be sorted from the Java Program. Ex If i wish to sort on Account Option num,then will pass the "AccountOptionNum" from Java, likewise Code,Bonus,Supplier etc.   The XSL shouldn't sort all the nodes except the one sent from the Java program.

Comment: Edit your answer and put that in.

Comment: Should Codes, Bonus, etc. be sorted within one `Account`, or should the Accounts be sorted within the document?

Comment: Hi, the Accounts should be sorted within the document. If we pass "Bonus" to be sorted from the Java Program then the "Bonus" node within all the "Account" nodes should be sorted within the document.

Comment: i have edited my question and added the input and output xml files.

Comment: Hi, Its working for me with the below XSL.  But just want to know how can we ignore namespaces if the XSML does use namespaces. Please help me ...<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"> <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/> <xsl:param name="sortNode"/> <xsl:param name="typeNode"/> <xsl:param name="orderNode"/> <xsl:template match="*"> <xsl:copy> <xsl:apply-templates> <xsl:sort select="*[name()=$sortNode]" data-type="{$typeNode}" order="{$orderNode}"/> </xsl:apply-templates> </xsl:copy> </xsl:template> </xsl:stylesheet>